# Stable group algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete group and let $C^*_r(G)$ be its reduced group C*-algebra. Is there any group $G$ for which we have $C^*_r(G)\cong M_2(C^*_r(G))$? Or more generally, $C^*_r(G) \cong C^*_r(G)\otimes \mathcal{K}(\ell_2)$?

Comment: For a discrete group, the reduced group $C^*$-algebra is always unital. Unital algebras cannot be stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for a discrete group $C^*_r(G)$ has a faithful tracial state. The compact operators cannot have such a state thus $C^*_r(G)$ cannot have the compact operators as a subalgebra. In fact using a little von Neumann algebra theory you can get that $C^*_r(G)$ cannot contain any compact operators at all.